# ¿Cómo manipular la selección de texto de un input field en YouTube?

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

Uso un [Userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) para cambiar ciertas funcionalidades de YouTube y estoy intentando bloquear el ["select all" en el `text field`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery) del enlace para compartir, allí donde pone la dirección del vídeo:

<kbd>[image: text field en YT]</kbd>

<sup>el motivo es que no necesito el `https://` y hago ese copiar/pegar a menudo</sup>

El *text field* solo aparece en el DOM después de pinchar al botón <kbd>Share</kbd>. He conseguido quitar la propiedad `focus` con el script abajo, pero el *"select all"* sigue activo:

```
// Botón "Share"
$('button[data-trigger-for="action-panel-share"]').on('click', function() {      
    window.setTimeout (function(){ 
        // Input field con la URL - no hay onclick, pero por si acaso
        $("input[name=share_url]").prop('onclick',null).prop('focus',null); 
    },300);
});
```

He intentado buscar por `share_url` en el Depurador JavaScript de Firefox pero no he encontrado la propiedad que tengo que quitar para conseguir el comportamiento deseado...

Cómo solución alternativa, acabo de intentar sustituir el contenido del `input`, pero automáticamente vuelve a su valor original (!!!).

```
var nueva_url = $("input[name=share_url]").val();
nueva_url = nueva_url.replace('https://','');
$("input[name=share_url]").val(nueva_url);
```

PS: La página de YT no viene con jQuery por defecto, pero para hacer pruebas es posible inyectarlo a través de la consola usando el [siguiente script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573284/1287812):

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, el objetivo es obtener el la URL sin el prefijo de `https://` ¿te funcionaría un script que te devuelva el texto en consola? creo yo que es lo más eficaz y eficiente.

Comment: Si, el objetivo es copiar fácilmente la URL sin el prefijo, pero la solución alternativa más fácil me parece hacer un `window.prompt`. La solución en la consola implica `ctrl+shift+i`, seleccionar y copiar, cuando lo ideal es simplemente el click en "share" y copiar el texto que ya viene seleccionado.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es copiar la URL, ¿por qué no añadir esa funcionalidad directamente al botón de compartir? No quiero sonar crítico, pero parece que estás reinventando la rueda cuando podrías hacerlo de una manera aún más sencilla si aplicases un enfoque diferente. De esta manera, necesitas 4 clicks para copiar la URL (1 en Share, 2 en la caja de texto, 3 el secundario para el menu, 4 seleccionar la opción de copiar). Pero podrías automatizarlo (por ejemplo [basándose en esta otra pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/621)) y hacerlo en un solo click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Nota: Sé que esta respuesta no se corresponde de manera directa a tu pregunta, pero sí es una alternativa que logra el objetivo deseado [especificado en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368/c%C3%B3mo-manipular-la-selecci%C3%B3n-de-texto-de-un-input-field-en-youtube#comment927_368): "cómo copiar una versión modificada de la URL de la caja de texto".

Podrías automatizar ese proceso sin necesidad de preocuparte por los eventos de la caja de texto que contiene la URL (e incluso sin preocuparte por el campo porque la URL corta también se puede encontrar en una etiqueta `link` con `rel="shortlink"`).

Aparte de la opción de usar un `prompt` que mencionas en el comentario, también podrías utilizar la API del portapapeles (clipboard) de JavaScript si usas un navegador moderno (Chrome 42+, IE10+, Firefox 41+, Opera 29+, pero no Safari) [cómo se especifica en esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/621/copiar-el-contenido-de-un-elemento-al-portapapeles-usando-javascript).

El código en jQuery sería sencillo:

```
$("button[data-trigger-for='action-panel-share']").on("click", function() { 
    var $temp = $("<input>")
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($("link[rel='shortlink']").attr("href").replace("https://", "")).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
});
```

O alternativamente sin jQuery:

```
var s = document.querySelector("button[data-trigger-for='action-panel-share']");
s.onclick = function() { 
   var aux = document.createElement("input");
   aux.setAttribute("value", document.querySelector("link[rel='shortlink']").href.replace("https://", ""));
   document.body.appendChild(aux);
   aux.select();
   document.execCommand("copy");
   document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
```

Ahora, ya no tienes que preocuparte por los diferentes eventos asociados a la caja de texto, y consigues el mismo objetivo con solo un click.

Comment: Genial la solución, creo que había caído en un Problema XY cómo bien apuntaste en tu comentario a la pregunta.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes contrarrestarlo con un [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:text").focus(function() {
    $(this).select();
  });
  $("#unbinder").click(function() {
    $("input:text").off();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="hola mundo!" />
<button id="unbinder">click para quitar el select all</button>
```

Comment: No ha funcionado allí en YouTube... :/ Creo que el problema es descubrir qué usa YT para gestionar ese comportamiento...

Comment: Tengo bloqueado el youtube, pero pienso que el evento no está en el input propiamente.

Comment: Parece que lo que usa YT es mucho más poderoso que jQuery o.O He actualizado la pregunta con un test que acabo de hacer y hay algún Listener actuando allí que no deja ni cambiar el valor del `input`...

Comment: revisaste si tiene requirejs? Esos son los únicos componentes que he visto que al cambiarles su valor vuelven al original

Comment: no lo veo, pero los `.js` parecen bien *obfuscated*...