# ¿Cómo Copiar al portapeles el valor de un elemento con Formato?

Tags: javascript

//En el momento este código sólo Copia pero no lo hace conservando el formato

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<b><p id="demo">Caso con formato.</p></b>
 <button onclick="ejecutar('demo')">Copiar</button>  <BR><BR>

<script>

function ejecutar(idelemento){
     var aux = document.createElement("input");
  aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(idelemento).innerHTML);
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que ese es mi código, gracias por apuntar los fallos. Lo he modificado un poco y ahora te pongo una respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen ojo. Ese código no va a funcionar correctamente si quieres que se copie el formato porque lo que se está haciendo es copiar el contenido del elemento indicado como valor de un `input` de tipo `text` por lo que el código HTML se va a "perder".

Una solución sería copiar el contenido del elemento a un `div` que sea `contentEditable`, de ese modo el formato no se perderá cuando se copie. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

> Nota: he modificado un poco tu HTML porque no era válido y nunca se iba a copiar el formato

Dale al botón de copiar y luego pulsa en la caja de texto (es un `div` editable y pega el texto). Ahora se copiará con negrita.

```js
function ejecutar(idelemento){
  var aux = document.createElement("div");
  aux.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
  aux.innerHTML = document.getElementById(idelemento).innerHTML;
  aux.setAttribute("onfocus", "document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)"); 
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.focus();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
```

```css
#destino {
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"><b>Caso con formato.</b></p>
<button onclick="ejecutar('demo')">Copiar</button> 


<div id="destino" contentEditable="true">
</div>
```