# Copiar al portapapeles dato que viene de un ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo una vista que trae la información con un `ng-repeat`, necesito poner un botón al final que cuando se de click copie al portapapeles lo que hay en el campo pedido, el tema es que los pedidos salen de un `ng-repeat`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así llegan los datos:

[image]

El código en el html está así, el dato que necesito llevar al portapapeles es el que esta en data.pedido:

> ```
>                                                   <tr ng-repeat="data in contingenciasPortafolio track by $index"ng-class="{'resaltado15min': data.horagestion <= quinceminutos[indice]}">
>                                                         <td>
>                                                             <center>
>                                                                 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.bloqueo" name="bloqueo" id="bloqueo" ng-change="marcarEnGestionPortafolio(data)">
>                                                             </center>
>                                                         </td>
> ```

```
                                                        <td><span ng-class="{'label label-primary label-xsmall': data.enGestionPortafolio == 1}" >{{data.loginContingenciaPortafolio}}</span></td>
                                                        <td>{{data.pedido}}</td>                                        
                                                        <td><center>{{data.macEntra}}</center></td>
                                                        <td><center>{{data.macSale}}</center></td>
                                                        <td><center>{{data.ciudad}}</center></td>
                                                        <td><center>{{data.proceso}}</center></td>
                                                        <td><center>{{data.accion}}</center></td>
                                                        <td><center>{{data.horagestion}}</center></td>
                                                        <td><center>{{data.producto}}</center></td>
                                                        <td><center>{{data.tipoEquipo}}</center></td>
                                                        <td><center>{{data.remite}}</td>
```

Leí en otra publicación [como copiar datos al portapapeles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/621/copiar-el-contenido-de-un-elemento-al-portapapeles-usando-javascript) pero lo hacen con el id del input, acá al ser dinámico no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Hector, dices que el problema es en un código que se genera con un `ng-repeat` pero en el código que compartes no hay ningún `ng-repeat`, sería bueno que añadieras un poco más de código. También sería bueno que añadieras un ejemplo de lo que hayas intentado para copiar, así como un enlace a la otra publicación que leíste ([¿ésta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/621/250)) para que el resto de usuarios tengan una referencia a lo que has intentado (quizás haya errores que hayas pasado por alto). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación, ya edite mi duda y lo tendré presente para próximas publicaciones.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Logre solucionar de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el vínculo donde encontré como [copiar contenidos en el portapapeles](https://www.diariodeunprogramador.net/javascript-copiar-contenidos-en-el-portapapeles/)

Comment: podrias agregar el texto en vez de una imagen?